# mysql.sock problem on Mac OS X, all Zend products

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, zend-server

I posted this on the [Zend forum](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=596&p=16223#p16223), but I'm hoping I can get a speedier reply here. I've tried every solution provided on this forum with no luck. When I restart mysql, everything appears ok.

```
sudo /usr/local/zend/bin/zendctl.sh restart 
Password:
/usr/local/zend/bin/apachectl stop [OK]
/usr/local/zend/bin/apachectl start [OK]
Stopping Zend Server GUI [Lighttpd] [OK]
spawn-fcgi: child spawned successfully: PID: 7943
Starting Zend Server GUI [Lighttpd] [OK]
Stopping Java bridge [OK]
Starting Java bridge [OK]
Shutting down MySQL
. SUCCESS! 
Starting MySQL
. SUCCESS!
```

Pinging locahost is also OK and resolve dns to IP.

```
ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.064 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.066 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.076 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.064 ms
```

But when I attempt to access the local url for my app, I get the dreaded:

Message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2).

This is a show-stopper for me. I appreciate any assistance. 
Thank you.

Comment: so, here's an update...
my 'puter has lost it's mind. all kinds of whacko stuff has been happening. my guess is that this issue is more a symptom of a larger problem. so, yesterday, i wiped and rebuilt it. today, i get to start over and hopefully return to happy developer's land. 

both answers appear quite helpful. i appreciate the responses. i'll mark them as such, but i don't know if either solves my issues because i think this issue is a "red herring". thanks for the help. how do i give each credit for your efforts?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the socket location in your application config file. If you set it for your local dev environment by adding the following line:

```
resources.db.params.unix_socket = /usr/local/zend/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
```

No more need to link the socket by hand.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's idea of `localhost` isn't the IETF's idea of `localhost`.  To MySQL, `localhost` means "a Unix socket of random location", which is the cause of endless frustration (and, in all likelihood, anal warts and global warming).  If you want to use a Unix socket, then you'll need to configure Zend to use the correct socket (I don't know how, nobody seems to be able to decide on a standard location for the socket, nor a standard way to tell everything else where it is).  Honestly just changing your server address to `127.0.0.1`, which means "localhost, no really, I'm not kidding, yeah, the real one on the network" is a far less frustrating way to go (just make sure you've told MySQL itself to listen on the network by removing `skip-networking`).

Answer (score 1):

Check your **/etc/mysql/my.cnf** and see what socket is set to under your [mysqld] section. Then, you can either change that to **/tmp/mysql.sock** or just make a symlink to where it puts it, e.g.

```
ln -s /var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Of course most *nix OS's wipe /tmp on shutdown so the first method is probably best, unless you're me and think that the socket has no business being in /tmp

And on a side note, you should check out the Python framework [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/), it made me happily leave Zend Framework in the dust.

Comment: thx for the comment. but when the boss says "zend framework", then that's what we do -- nowatimsayin'. ;-)

Comment: Indeed I do. :)

Answer (score 0):

The default Mac Zend install creates the socket file here:

/usr/local/zend/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock

Take a look at the "socket" variable in your "my.cnf" file located in "/usr/local/zend/mysql/data" to identify where it is or move it to a more convenient spot.